# ArcMap sometimes ignores labeling expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3, python-parser

I'm using this python script as an expression for labeling in ArcMap:

```
def FindLabel ( [volkorrekt] ):
 if [volkorrekt] >= '5':
  return "<FNT size = '20'>"+  str( [volkorrekt] )+"</FNT>"
 elif [volkorrekt] >= '2':
   return  "<FNT size = '14'>"+  str( [volkorrekt] )+"</FNT>"
 elif [volkorrekt] >= '1':
  return "<FNT size = '8'>"+  str( [volkorrekt] )+"</FNT>"
 else:
  return ""
```

I want ArcMap to only label the feature if the value `volkorrekt` is bigger than 1, **this is working**. I also want ArcMap to change the font size according to my if-statement (font size 20 if value >= 5, 14 if >= 2 and 8 if >= 1) but **this only works for some but not for all features**.

This is my current result:

[image]

Examples for wrong labels: The "19,487..." is displayed very small though it's one of the biggest values, the "9,552..." however is displayed much to large.

**How can I get ArcMap to label the features in the way I described?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing numbers and text. What type of field is *vollkorrekt*?

As it is now, you are comparing the value to a string, i.e. `[vollkorrekt] >= '1'`. The comparison is therefore alphabetical instead of numeric, meaning that '19' is smaller than '5', but bigger than '1'.

If the type of the field is *numeric*, you only have to remove the single quotes: `if [volkorrekt] >= 5:` etc.

If the type of the field is *text*, you have to convert the value to a float: `if float([volkorrekt]) >= 5:`

Here's the complete code, modified to increase readability:

```py
def FindLabel( [volkorrekt] ):
    value = float( [volkorrekt].replace(',', '.' ))
    if value >= 5:
        size = 20
    elif value >= 2:
        size = 14
    elif value >= 1:
        size = 8
    else:
        return ""

    return "<FNT size='{0}'>{1}</FNT>".format(size, value)
```

Comment: The type of volkorrekt is double. I removed the single quotes, now all of my labels are in font size 20 AND also the values < 1 are displayed.

Comment: @Simon Sorry, my bad. I should actually have tried the code in ArcGIS. It seems that the value is passed to the FindLabel methode as a string already, even if the field is text. You need to convert it back to a float, taking into account the system's decimal character.

Answer (score 8):

This is because you try to use `>` as a character in your label, as well as for formatting/programming your label. Nothing wrong with that, it's how it works. But if you want to use those characters in your label you need to *escape* them.

Instead of the actual characther you need to use `&lt;` (<), `&gt;` (>) and `&amp;` (&).

An alternative approach is to use label classes. Then you can have SQL queries instead of your IF statements, which IMO is easier to control.